# What is the best (performance) way to animate 55 png images in Adobe Flash?

Tags: flash

We are using Adobe Flash to produce software for an interactive touch screen kiosk.  I have 55 1024x768 24 bit PNG images.  I want to play them (fairly regularly...once every 5 minutes or so) without them stuttering but can't find a good dependable way, main problem is I think Flash GC's them after an arbitrary idle period.  Reason I'm doing this is because the FLV attempts we have made aren't sufficiently high quality.  I also looked at using a H.264 but that obscures any other assets placed over it.  I have a number of text fields sitting over this animation.

The machine in question is a Core2 Duo, 4GB Ram, GeForce 9500GT.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you attempting to load these images dynamically?

Comment: They are all compiled into a SWC

Comment: What indicates that the images are being garbage collected?

Comment: Not much, I was hoping someone would have some pixelblender/flv/264 voodoo to throw on the table to improve the role of flash at something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd do an FLV.

Here is what I did:

1. Created a new project: 1024 x 768
2. Created the order of the pics in the timeline in separate frame.
3. Exported using QuickTime H.264
4. Converted to the FLV listed above.

Comment: + 1. Flash player 9 has a bug on GC. Try using Flash player 10.

Comment: Hard to tell with fades, could you try some motion.  That, in any codec, tends to be where the decay occures.  What did you convert to FLV with.